# Tracking referrals from non-internet resources

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

One can see the URL of the site (also called **[referrers](http://searchengineland.com/how-to-get-full-referral-content-urls-from-google-analytics-149549)**) which pushed the visitor to your site.

The site owner can also share links to non-website based sources such as chat software, email etc.

I was trying to understand how can one **track non-website based referrers in Google analytics** such as:

- User coming from email links
- User clicking from chat messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add URL parameters to track a visitor from external sources that do not provide referrer data.

this may help you:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en